# Why is this question considered as primarily opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

I wonder why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325101/best-practice-to-modify-object) is closed for being  primarily opinion-based when it is not.

There are highly-scored posts of similar questions with very objective answers (I randomly pick [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178328/in-php-5-0-is-passing-by-reference-faster/3845530#3845530)) that can be combined to provide an answer for the OP.

The question could be marked at worst as a duplicate, but not a primarily opinion-based one.

Comment: "best practice" questions are most probably primary-based opinion.

Comment: Your random example is from a very different time on SO, and asks an objective question (Is X faster?).

Comment: There's no indication whatsoever that the OP means performance. The question unclear on top of being primarily opinion based.

Comment: Cross site dupe. This is why. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question you link to is asking specifically what is *faster*. This is a specific objectively answerable question.

"What is best practice?" is vague. Best practice in terms of what? CPU utilisation? Execution time? Memory usage? Readability? Compatibility? Line count? Something else?

Some people might think readability is important, while others might emphasize memory usage, this is a matter of opinion. It's also a matter of opinion what exactly is "readable", or "desirable". None of these opinions come into play on the older question, as it specifically asks something quantifiable. You can measure execution time.

There is a subtle yet significant difference between these two questions ;-)